# Cannot set properties of null (setting 'disabled')

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having the following error come up in the console whenever I run my code.
I am trying to set elements with the id custominput to be enabled ii the selector value is custom, but disabled if it is anything else. custominput elements are text inputs part of a form.

```
Cannot set properties of null (setting 'disabled')
```

```js
console.log('working');

var selector = document.getElementById("qset");
var custominp = document.getElementById("custominput");

console.log(selector.value);

custominp.disabled = false;

selector.addEventListener("change", qsetChange);

function qsetChange() {
  if (selector.value === "custom") {
    console.log('in loop', selector.value);
    custominp.disabled = true;
  } else {
    console.log(selector.value);
    custominp.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  background-color: rgb(52, 65, 96);
}

form.hostoptions {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #9edfff;
  border-color: #9edfff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}

.formtextinput {
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<form class='hostoptions' action="gamescreen">

  <label for="obstacles">% obstacles on track</label><br>
  <input type="range" id="obs" name="obstacles" min="0" max="100" value="5" step="1" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value">
  <output>5</output>%

  <br>

  <label for="qset">Question set:</label>
  <select class="qset" id="qset" name="qset">
    <option value="q1" selected>Q1</option>
    <option value="q2">Q2</option>
    <option value="q3">Q3</option>
    <option value="custom">Custom</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <div id="customQ">
    Custom: <input class='custominput' type="text" name="last_name" disabled=true/>
  </div>
  <br><br>

  <input class="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Start Game">

</form>
```

Comment: Is your JS running before the DOM loads?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier the script is just placed fine. The issue is that the script is calling for an Id while no element with that Id exsist but one with a class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you use `getElementById` while `custominput` is a class. use `querySelector` instead:

```js
console.log('working');

var selector = document.getElementById("qset");
var custominp = document.querySelector(".custominput");

console.log(selector.value);

custominp.disabled = false;

selector.addEventListener("change", qsetChange);

function qsetChange() {
  if (selector.value === "custom") {
    console.log('in loop', selector.value);
    custominp.disabled = true;
  } else {
    console.log(selector.value);
    custominp.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  background-color: rgb(52, 65, 96);
}

form.hostoptions {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #9edfff;
  border-color: #9edfff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}

.formtextinput {
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<form class='hostoptions' action="gamescreen">

  <label for="obstacles">% obstacles on track</label><br>
  <input type="range" id="obs" name="obstacles" min="0" max="100" value="5" step="1" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value">
  <output>5</output>%

  <br>

  <label for="qset">Question set:</label>
  <select class="qset" id="qset" name="qset">
    <option value="q1" selected>Q1</option>
    <option value="q2">Q2</option>
    <option value="q3">Q3</option>
    <option value="custom">Custom</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <div id="customQ">
    Custom: <input class='custominput' type="text" name="last_name" disabled=true/>
  </div>
  <br><br>

  <input class="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Start Game">

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your input does not have id="custominput" it has class="custominput"
Change it to:

```
<input id='custominput' type = "text" name ="last_name" disabled=true/>
```